# how does reference work in linked lists when the referred node changes value?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

i want to understand how the temp still refers to the first current node even though the current node changed through the loop. any help is appreciated.

```
  public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode() {}
    ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ListNode temp = new ListNode(0) ;
    ListNode current = temp ;
   for(int i = 1; i <10 ; i++ ) {
       current.next = new ListNode(i) ;
       current = current.next ;
   }
    System.out.println(current.val); // output : 9
    System.out.println(temp.next.val); // output : 1
     System.out.println(temp.next.next.val); // output : 2
}

   }
```

Comment: Because you never assign `temp` to anything else. You only change `current`, but that's a different variable. You could remove `temp` and just use `ListNode current = ListNode(0);` and your program would behave the same.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: `ListNode current = temp;` is merely an assignment.  An assignment merely copies data, at the time it is executed, from the right side of `=` to the variable on the left side of `=`.  It does *not* mean “current will be equal to temp, at all times, forever.”

Comment: In Java, two variables may refer to the same object, but never will reassigning one of those variables also reassign the other.

Comment: @Slaw - it should be made clear that updating the object will affect all references to that object. In some cases, such as iterators, it may not be clear. Unlike C++ std::iterator, where assigning one iterator to another creates a new iterator object, with Java, both iterators will reference the same object. For example, if `it` and `jt` are iterators, `it = jt`  results in both referencing the same iterator object and either `it.next()` or `jt.next()` will update both `it` and `jt` since they reference the same iterator object.

Comment: @rcgldr True. My comment is focused on the reference to the object (i.e., variable), not the object itself. And yes, C++ will copy the object itself unless you use a pointer or reference. But in Java, objects are never copied on assignment. All object-typed variables are references, and the _references_ are passed by value.

Comment: IMO the question should be 'Why changing a reference's value does not change the other that's pointing to the same object'

Answer (score 1):

When you do this,

```
 ListNode temp = new ListNode(0) ;
 ListNode current = temp ;
```

`temp` and `current` are just two references to an object of `ListNode` and not objects (they are just aliases to represent an object's names). `current` and `temp` are now pointing to the same object, `ListNode(0)`. When you do this

```
current.next = new ListNode(i) ;
current = current.next ;
```

When `i` is 1, you change the reference `next` in `ListNode(0)` to point to `ListNode(1)`, through `current` (this doesn't change or affect `temp`). Then you change `current` to point to `ListNode(1)` (this also doesn't change or affect `temp`). As the loop continues, you repeat the same process for different `i` value.

So `temp` still not changed, still pointing to `ListNode(0)` because you only change the `current` to point to different object. Maybe for your code the purpose of `temp` is to point the head of list, thus should be named `head`.